# Fedora 24 vs NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, fedora

Как поставить на этого зверя npm? DNF выдаёт такое вот, в гугле есть тема с багом на форуме Федоры и всё(

`Last metadata expiration check: 3:25:17 ago on Sat Aug  6 12:29:39 2016.
Error: installed package nodejs-1:4.4.7-2.fc24.x86_64 obsoletes npm < 3.5.4-6 provided by npm-3.5.4-5.fc24.noarch`

Comment: не знаю как в федоре, но у меня npm идет в пакете вместе с node

Comment: @yurish ничего подбного(

Comment: можно попробовать через nvm еще